# Chunk generation version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing in my world for several versions now. Is there any way for me to figure out in which version, the chunk I stand in, is created?

Comment: haha good question, but I doubt there is a way

Comment: At best, you're probably looking at a min and max range, and that's assuming it's basically undisturbed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no. You might be able to figure it out with some detective work:

1. Know what version you first generated the world with.
2. Know what versions you have played it with between now and then.
3. Know the [version numbers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history) in which various world generation details or large-scale algorithm changes occurred. A non-exhaustive list is:

- Beta 1.2 added sandstone under sand blocks in deserts
- Beta 1.7 didn't generate very much clay
- Beta 1.8 drastically changed the terrain generator, which can show as straight lines of mis-matched blocks and biomes, where one chunk was generated with the pre-1.8 algorithm and one was generated after

  - Structures (strongholds, villages, abandoned mines, and ravines) were added
  - New biomes are rivers, oceans, swamp
  - Ocean/swamp floor is now a mix of sand, dirt, and clay
- 1.0.0 added mushroom biomes
- 1.2.1 added wooden bridges in abandoned mineshafts where the cave, mineshaft, or ravine generator created a gap
- 1.3.1 added emerald ore, desert-themed villages, temples, taller hills in sub-biomes (such as desert hills or ice mountains)

4. Use your knowledge of (1) and (2) to narrow down the useful clues from (3), then use the clues from (3) as forensic markers to investigate the heritage of a given chunk.
5. Develop a taste for digital archaeology. You may wish to install a mod that gives you [a dashing hat and bullwhip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_jones).